# GooglePlayServices login fails for a Unity game

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

#### The problem

I have an alpha version of an Android game made in Unity. This game has integration with Google Play Services, which was accomplished using the [Play Games Plugin for Unity](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity). **I'm trying to log into Google Play Services, and while myself and other test users get the initial login animation, ultimately the login callback fails.**

#### Things that I've checked:

- The APK was accepted and is signed with an appropriate keystore.
- The Android project is linked with the Play Services one.
- I have created an alpha version and deployed it in the platform.
- My Google account, that I've used for logging in, is in the alpha channel.

  - Said channel is active for the game's alpha.
- The application is available for all countries.
- I installed the Android 9.0 SDK and all Google modules using Android Studio.
- I'm using Android 9.0 on my phone, same as the installed SDK.
- I'm using the latest version of the Play Games for Unity plugin.
- I copied the GPGS resources and initialized the GPG plugin; all OK and no warnings.
- The game was built on release mode and not debug mode.
- The game and the Play Services are ready and have no pending tasks in the platform.

Does somebody know what I might be missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to login after following the invitation link and pressing "become a tester", this is what I was missing. I thought that being in the tester email list was enough, but apparently not. This was unintuitive to me as there are no descriptive error messages when a login fails, at least with the tools that I'm using.